# How to pass self to a constructor

Tags: python, class, oop

Consider the following class:

```
class WebPageTestProcessor:

    def __init__(self,url,harUrl):
        self.url = url
        self.harUrl = harUrl

    def submitTest():
        response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
        return response["data"]["testId"]

def main():
    wptProcessor = WebPageTestProcessor("http://www.webpagetest.org/runtest.php?f=json&priority=6&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.target.com%2F&runs=3&video=1&web10=0&fvonly=1&mv=1&k=d3ebfa90cb4e45a9bb648e7ebf852321")
    print wptProcessor.submitTest()

if  __name__ =='__main__':main()
```

Upon running, it throws an error saying:

```
 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given).
```

I passed `None` as the argument:

```
wptProcessor = WebPageTestProcessor(None,"http://www.webpagetest.org/runtest.php?f=json&priority=6&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.target.com%2F&runs=3&video=1&web10=0&fvonly=1&mv=1&k=d3ebfa90cb4e45a9bb648e7ebf852321")
```

and then it says:

```
TypeError: submitTest() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Does anyone know how to pass `self` to the constructor?

Comment: you are not passing `harUrl` and you need to add self to `submitTest(self)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass 2 arguments to`WebPageTestProcessor` class `url` and `harUrl`

You are passing only 1 which is

```
"http://www.webpagetest.org/runtest.php?f=json&priority=6&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.target.com%2F&runs=3&video=1&web10=0&fvonly=1&mv=1&k=d3ebfa90cb4e45a9bb648e7ebf852321"
```

The self variable represents the instance of the object itself, you can rename it to any name you want.

The problem is your order, try:

```
class WebPageTestProcessor(object):
    def __init__(self,url,harUrl):
        self.url = url
        self.harUrl = harUrl

    def submitTest(self):
        response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(self.url))
        return response["data"]["testId"]

def main():
    wptProcessor = WebPageTestProcessor("http://www.webpagetest.org/runtest.php?f=json&priority=6&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.target.com%2F&runs=3&video=1&web10=0&fvonly=1&mv=1&k=d3ebfa90cb4e45a9bb648e7ebf852321", None)
    print wptProcessor.submitTest()

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

At the above code we have fixed 3 issues:

1. Setting self to `submitTest` method.
2. using the `self.url` inside `submitTest` method since it's a class attribute.
3. fixing the instance creation of the class by passing 2 arguments as we declared.

Comment: Thanks the error was confusing as it said 3 required two given . I accidentally thought I has passed the harUrl.

Comment: @user567797 NP the answer solved the issue you can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is also passed implicitly to all non-static methods of a class.  You need to define `submitTest` like so:

```
def submitTest(self):
#              ^^^^
    response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(self.url))
#                                       ^^^^^
    return response["data"]["testId"]
```

You'll notice too that I placed `self.` before `url`.  You need this because `url` is an instance attribute of the class (it is only accessible through `self`).

Comment: where is url going to come from in `json.load(urllib.urlopen(url))`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Good catch.  I'll mention that.